# Trying to load local file in stage via Snowflake PUT command but command gets greyed out

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple requirement where I have to put a file in snowflake internal stage.

put file:///Users/priya/Downloads/vistaslagos.csv @canary2022/apartments;

When I try the above, the command is getting greyed out.

I further tried putting single quotes like below but I am getting the error :-->000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'unsupported_requested_format:snowflake'.

put 'file:///Users/priya/Downloads/vistaslagos.csv' @canary2022/apartments;

On further checking the error, it says I need to validate the snowflake edition.

Does anyone has context in this?

Comment: [Usage Notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#usage-notes): 
"**The command cannot be executed from the Worksheets Worksheet tab page in either Snowflake web interface;** instead, use the SnowSQL client to upload data files, or check the documentation for a specific Snowflake client to verify support for this command."

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are trying to run the command in worksheets(UI). When you do so and give file:///, it considers the further text in the line as comments which is why you see it as greyed out.

Put command cannot be submitted in UI which is why you see the error feature not supported.

Try using snowsql and this should work. It is also mentioned in official documentation as well. Comments and Links for your reference below.

"The command cannot be executed from the Worksheets Worksheet tab page in either Snowflake web interface; instead, use the SnowSQL client to upload data files, or check the documentation for a specific Snowflake client to verify support for this command"

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#usage-notes

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT do this in the Worksheets using the `PUT` command.

> But, you **CAN** do this in the UI:

1. Navigate to the main UI -> Data -> Databases

   1. [image: UI -> Data -> Databases Left Navigation]
2. Navigate to Your Created `STAGE`

   1. [image: Navigate to your Schema -> STAGE in second left column Navigation]
3. In the Main section: Select the `+ FILES` in the top right and upload here!

   1. [image: Navigate to the blue button for FILES and upload.]
4. You will then see a File Uploader:

   1. [image: File Uploader]